# Adding PPF/PPFD / Scaling

Tags: led, light, lighting, flux

When considering PPF or PPFD, can you multiply the PPF of the light source by a factor (for example x100) and divide the calculated PPFD value by it to obtain the same results? In another way - is PPF linearly scalable?

Also - can you switch between light distribution in [lux] and apply this distribution to calculate PPFD?

Answer (score 0):

If the light source does not change the angle and distribution of light when you increase the power to it then, yes.